# .htaccess rule conflict with previous defined rules

Tags: .htaccess

Right now I have the following .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)_([0-9]+)/$ index.php?section_permalink=$1&content_permalink=$2&content_id=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/p-([0-9]+)/$ index.php?section_permalink=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?section_permalink=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Everything works fine, but if I add the following rule, every time I try to access /route/10/ (for example) I get redirected to the home page.

```
RewriteRule ^route/(.*)/$ route.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can I rewrite this rule to avoid this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Place the `^route/` rule _first_ since it is more specific than the ones which follow it.  mod_rewrite rules are heavily order dependent.

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule`s are executed in the order they are in the file. `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?section_permalink=$1 [QSA,L]` matches the url and the url is rewritten to `index.php?section_permalink=route/10`. This doesn't match your next rewriterule.

Swapping the more specific rule and and the more-or-less catch-all rule will solve the issue, since the more specific rule will be matched first.